# JS Regex to extract all URL from a Text to array of URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to pull out all the URLs from a text entered by the user by doing the following but am not able to get the desired result.

```
let regexp = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/igm;
let str = "https://mysleepyhead.com http://skreem.io";

let array = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];

console.log(array);
```

Desired output would be

```
Array ['https://mysleepyhead.com', 'http://skreem.io']
```

Comment: `^` and `$` anchor to the beginning and end of the line. If the string you're dealing with is composed of multiple possible matches in a single line, don't use those anchors. https://regex101.com/r/q89Ipv/1 (you also probably want `.match`, not `.matchAll`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance i tried that. but when i do a match i am getting back null. would you be able to share a jsfidle or something.

Comment: `"https://mysleepyhead.com http://skreem.io".match(/(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+/igm)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance some reason its matching other data as well. https://jsfiddle.net/4ubpL9we/

Comment: You made the leading `http` optional. Maybe you want to make sure the match contains at least one `.` in it? `(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?(?=[a-z])[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+(?:\/\S*)?` or something of the sort

Comment: Where the question is actually already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719443/1397641